# 415 Unsupported MediaType Error

Tags: android, https

I am uploading a Photo to the server using HTTPS POST request. The request is Multipart and I am using this code to upload the pic.

```
 public HttpResponse uploadPhoto(File imagePath) {

    try {

        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
                "https://wbapi.cloudapp.net:443/api/Submission/UploadCompetitionEntry?folderName=photos");

        MultipartEntity multipartEntity = new MultipartEntity(
                HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

        httppost.setHeader( "Content-Type", "multipart/form-data" );
        httppost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        httppost.setHeader("Authorization", getAuth());
        multipartEntity.addPart("CompetitionID", new StringBody("84"));
        multipartEntity.addPart("UserId", new StringBody(""
                + LoginActivity.id_user));
        multipartEntity.addPart("Title", new StringBody(""
                + edit_title.getText().toString()));
        multipartEntity.addPart("Summary", new StringBody(""
                + edit_description.getText().toString()));
        multipartEntity.addPart("photos", new FileBody(imagePath,"image/jpeg"));
        multipartEntity.addPart("MediaType", new StringBody("Photo"));
        multipartEntity.addPart("Visibility", new StringBody("Public"));
        multipartEntity.addPart("DateCreated", new StringBody(
                "2013-01-04T10:07:46.9450000Z"));
        httppost.setEntity(multipartEntity);
        http = mHttpClient.execute(httppost);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.v("Exception", "" + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return http;
}
```

and my HTTPClient is this

```
mHttpClient = WinboutServerRequests.getHTTPClientObject();
```

This takes care of the HTTPS Certificate stuff with Helper classes.

When I am doing the request, I am getting e.getMessage() as null and in StackTrace I am getting this

I have to send these entities to the server

Request to be sent

### Request

> curl -X POST "https://wbapi.cloudapp.net:443/api/Submission/UploadCompetitionEntry?folderName=photos" -F "Summary=My description" -F "CompetitionID=84" -F "Title=photo titile" -F "MediaType=Photo" -F "AuthorName=dog" -F "UserId=1251" -F "DateCreated=2013-01-04T10:07:46.9450000Z" -F "Visibility=Public" -F "photos=@/Users/akshayhegde/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/D8A03B97-B7CC-4655-8987-8A54AE3E5FFC/Documents/UserData/competitionEntry/photoEntryHeaderImage.jpg;type=application/octet-stream"

Answer :

There was this Authorisation which has to be added to the header which was missing.I added it and Now I am not getting CientProtocolException.

Added Utility Function to get the MIME Type of the file

```
public static String getMimeType(String url)
{
    String type = null;
    String extension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(url);
    if (extension != null) {
        MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
        type = mime.getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
    }
    return type;
}
```

But I am getting 415 Unsupported Media Type error, What we have to set the ContentType for uploading Pictures ?

**Sample request to be sent :**

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="CompetitionID"

### 3

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="UserId"

### 1

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Title"

### caesar and hiro

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Summary"

### window

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="MediaType"

### Video

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="DateCreated"

### 2012-06-07T02:17:57.09

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Visibility"

### Public/Private

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="photos"; filename=IMG_9322.JPG

### Content-Type:application/octet-stream

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="videos"; filename=sample.avi

### Content-Type:application/octet-stream

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="music"; filename=sample.avi

### Content-Type:application/octet-stream

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="writings"; filename=sample.txt
Content-Type:application/octet-stream

Comment: I guess the above code is 'correct' .. problem must be from `WinboutServerRequests.getHTTPClientObject();` You should check there..or show that code.

Comment: Try `multipart/form-data` for the Content-Type header, and `image/jpeg` for the image part. (You can probably programmatically get the MIME type of the file, though. That would be a better idea.)

Comment: @zneak I tried adding "multipart/form-data" check the edited code in the question

Comment: @RajeevNB, and do you get anything different now? Did you also update the `curl` request?

Comment: @zneak No I am getting the same 415 error. I did not update curl request,But I added a utility function check it out in the question