# How to solve error message "status": 415, "error": "Unsupported Media Type"," for DELETE request in Spring?

Tags: maven, spring-boot, request, spring-data, postman

I created a Spring Boot application based on [Service Components using this tutorial.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qJnAM_ZZvWA&list=PLGDwUiT1wr6-Fn3N2oqJpTdhGjFHnIIKY&index=4)

My delette request is constructed in the following way:

```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/api/greetings/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<Greeting> deleteGreeting(@PathVariable("id") Long id, @RequestBody Greeting greeting) {


    greetingService.delete(id);

    return new ResponseEntity<Greeting>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
    }
```

All the other requests work finally, but if I make the DELETE request in Postman I get the following error:

```
   {
"timestamp": 1519060345434,
"status": 415,
"error": "Unsupported Media Type",
"exception": "org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException",
"message": "Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' not supported",
"path": "/api/greetings/2"
```

}

I have checked the following issues, nothing helped (which is no wonder, none of them is issuing the DELETE request:

[415 Unsupported MediaType](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40218320/java-mongodb-post-415-unsupported-mediatype)

[415 Unsupported MediaType for POST request in spring application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38066591/415-unsupported-mediatype-for-post-request-in-spring-application)

[415 Unsupported Media Type in RESTful webservice
Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14151153/415-unsupported-mediatype-error)

Comment: you can use ```@RestController```  if your making some api and use ```@DeleteMapping``` anotations for your delete func.

Answer (score 1):

Your controller is expecting application/json as content-type but as the error message displays

```
"message": "Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' not supported",
```

you should change the header in postman to content-type application/json